# Ajax Call 400 Bad Request error with POST request but not with GET request

Tags: ajax

I created a Vanilla JS Ajax handler as follows:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    alert(this.responseText);
    }
};

xhttp.open("POST", ajaxurl, true);
xhttp.send("action=lalala");
}
```

And put this into the theme **functions.php** file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_lalala', 'lalala_ajax_test');

function lalala_ajax_test(){
    $reponse = array('test');
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}
```

And I am getting this in the browser console:

`POST https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)`

When I change the request to GET, as follows:

```
xhttp.open("GET", '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=lalala', true);
xhttp.send();
```

It works like a summer sunshine.

So, the error must be related with how the `action` parameter is passed when doing the request in POST mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is very probably going to help someone else sometime so here it goes:

Not setting the request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` makes the POST body behave like a string. So PHP does not recognize $_POST variables. To make that happen we need:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

So the whole thing goes like:

```
xhttp.open("POST", ajaxurl, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send("action=lalala");
```

And then it behaves as expected.